# How to query data in data table?

Tags: android, contacts

I used the following code to insert two row in data table:

```
ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI).withValue(
                RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null).withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME,
                null).build());

        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI).withValueBackReference(
                Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex).withValue(Data.MIMETYPE,
                StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE).withValue(StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME,
                "a").build());
        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI).withValueBackReference(
                Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex).withValue(Data.MIMETYPE,
                        GroupMembership.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE).withValue(CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID,
                        "groupa").build());
```

So i got two new line in data table.But when i want to get a contact's groupId which display_name is a, i don`t know how to do.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I feel more than content providers SQLite3 is a better option to work with.

Comment: But i am working on a project outside android source project, so it`s seems only way using content provider to fetch contacts database info. I am suffer from it.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer myself. RawContactsEntity can solve the problem properly.